# Inheritance between classes in python

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have 3 classes `A` , `B` and `C`. and both `B` and `C` inherit some variables from `A` class

Each of `B` and `C` classes have the same methods with the same logic but with a  little bit difference in variable names .

this the example:

```
class A(FilteredListView):
   model = book
   template_name = 'book.html'


class B(A, PatientObject):
    def get_queryset(self):
       instance = self.get_patient_instance_by_credential(**self.get_patient_details(self.kwargs.copy()))
       if instance:
          patient = Patient.objects.get(id=instance.id)
          content_type_id = ContentType.objects.filter(model="patient").values('id')
          logs = LogEntry.objects.filter(content_type_id=content_type_id, object_id=patient.id)
          users = set([get_user_model().objects.get(id=log.user_id) for log in logs])
          return {'log_entry': logs, 'user': users}
      return []

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
       context = super(B, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
       context['log_entry'] = self.kwargs.copy()
       return context




class C(A, PatientObject):
    def get_queryset(self):
       instance = self.get_patient_instance_by_credential(**self.get_patient_details(self.kwargs.copy()))
       episode_id = self.kwargs['pk']  # get the id of the pathway from the url
       if instance:
          episode = Episode.objects.get(patient=instance.id, id=episode_id)
          content_type_id =  ContentType.objects.filter(model="episode").values('id')
          logs = LogEntry.objects.filter(content_type_id=content_type_id, object_id=episode.id)
          users = set([get_user_model().objects.get(id=log.user_id) for log in logs])
          return {'log_entry': logs, 'user': users, 'episode': episode}
       return []

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
       context = super(C, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
       context['log_entry'] = self.kwargs.copy()
       return context
```

Is there a way to put the methods `get_queryset()` and `get_context_data()` in the parent class `A` with global variables?

And how to define variables for each child class ??

Comment: Multiple inheritance is not usually a good idea, have you thought about using composition instead?

Comment: I'm guessing `get_context_data` is defined in class `PatientObject`?

Comment: @dunno it's from `MultipleObjectMixin`  class of django